# ejabberd mod_stanza_ack where is source file and how to compile?

Tags: installation, ejabberd

I am installing the [acknowledgement erlang file written by mingism](https://github.com/Mingism/ejabberd-stanza-ack) but I am encountering problems.

According to the instructions:

```
erlc -I ${EJABBERD_SRC} mod_stanza_ack.erl
```

`{EJABBERD_SRC}` must be replaced with the actual location of *your ejabberd source files*, e.g. `/home/foobar/ejabberd/src`. An example of this folder can be found [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/tree/13.03-beta1/src).

The source files is what I couldn't find.

If anyone has tried out before could you please shed some light on this procedure.

Thank you.

Comment: I am installing on ubuntu

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the author of the mod.

Which version of ejabberd are you trying to install it to? Currently I am working on a stack which includes this functionality.

Comment: ejabberd2.1.11, I have been able to compile by getting the required files from sources and convert it to beam. Unfortunately , now my own smackx client can connect to ejabberd but not login. There is a socketexception sento failed error. I can login to ejabberd using spark client. The ackowledgement stanza seems to work as I can see a return acknowledgment message still in offline mode after I send message from spark. but I couldnt test its fully since  I am stuck now logging in to ejabberd. Any idea bro?

Comment: So your original question is resolved. I have no experience with SmackX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile correctly, get all the required files from installed ejabberd folder: logger.hrl, jlib.hrl, ns.hrl, ejabberd.hrl, and get the xml.hrl from the source of the link above in the question and then put the file in a new folder called p1_xml with a sub-folder called include and put that xml.hl there. and then compile in erlang compiler. It will compile with two errors but thats ok. put that file as mentioned in github instruction and also change the config and restart ejabberd. thats it!